# How I can see website url against google tracking ID

Tags: google-analytics

I want to ask that, I have access (not admin, only user access) to a GA tracking ID, but I am not able to see which website that ID is tracking. Is there a way in which I can see, which website is attached against a tracking ID? or if I can see from GA dashboard that which website is linked with this ID and which website's analytics data I am getting?

[This is the view I have access to.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnSa8.png)

Comment: This should be visible in the account settings

Comment: @B001ᛦ but I dont have admin access. So I can not see account settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Behavior>Site Content>All pages report, click on the pop-up icon next to the page path and if the domain has been properly set in the account settings, you'll get a pop-up view of the page - complete with entire url including domain.

Answer (score 0):

Set "hostname" as secondary dimension in the content reports, or create a custom report with hostname as primary dimension. That way you will get the actual domain that was tracked, even if the settings for the property or view are wrong.

This is especially useful if there is cross-domain-tracking (or just for debugging), since in the settings one can specify only one domain. However the tracking code might be (purposefully or accidentally) be deployed on multiple domains.